# Null when no parameter is selected in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: reporting, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I'm using Pentaho Report Designer Version: 8.0.0.0-28.

When no parameter is selected, I keep seeing NULL everywhere or just blank fields.
It seems that I have to set default values in each parameter.
I don't want anything to display if nothing is selected, and at the same time I don't want to have NULL and blank fields.

Any suggestions on what can I do instead?

Comment: Let’s say if you are using drop-down list and create parameter, then by default it will take the 1st value when you run the report. So ideally Null has not to come, so can you share your approach how you have created parameter and designed report ...

Comment: I have date pickers and drop down lists. Do I always have to set default value?

Comment: it depends on your functionality, how you want...

Comment: I'll see what other options are available, thank you for your time.